# Result source that only searches attachments in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, search, attachments, result-source

My requirement is to build a result source that searches documents and items in document libraries, and the contents of attachments of list items in non-document libraries.

Does anyone have an idea if it is possible to specifically search the contents of an attachement?

Answer (score 0):

You say "just documents" have you tried the query `IsDocument=1`? I haven't tested this against attachments, we don't use attachments in our farm, but this does return every document in our farm (that I have access to).